# Pass Active State to Carousel Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, carousel

Looking to have thumbnail photo / image popup into a bootstrap modal carousel, with an active state so it is selected as the starting point of the carousel. That modal carousel viewport area would then be displaying a larger version of the same photo / image via css.

Normally, Prettyphoto/gallery or the like can be used, but I'm looking for a way that does not draw upon a  source folder of images or html written within the script itself, but rather uses my existing unordered list of images, so I carry over the class names and use one set of images.

I experimented with many a carousel, but none carry over the active state with my existing list and or images combined. My motive for this is to allow another image to be overlayed on top via the classes: position-1, position-2, etc css classes.

I tried iframing the ul list to pass the class over but it did not work either.

The only way i can see Prettyphoto/Gallery working id the was a way for

Any direction is greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="carousel carousel-stage">
    <ul class="images thumbnails">
        <li id="design1" class="image span4 item thumbnail"><a rel="" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" title="" class="thumbnail-image position-1"><img src="img1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li id="design2" class="image span4 item thumbnail"><a rel="" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" title="" class="thumbnail-image position-2"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></li>
     ...
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Design Images</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="carousel carousel-stage">
    <ul class="images thumbnails">
        <li id="design1" class="image span4 item thumbnail"><a a rel="" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" title="" class="thumbnail-image position-1"><img src="img1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li id="design1" class="image span4 item thumbnail"><a a rel="" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" title="" class="thumbnail-image position-2"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></li>
     ...
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Boostrap don't have yet that function for carousel but achieving it you can combine carousel and modal. When clicked on thumbnail , modal shows up and get the full length image and put it in modal-body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's *one* possible solution that's kind of a hack but it seems to work okay.

Basically just moving parts of the DOM around and changing classes as needed. Maybe this can get you going in the right direction.

```
<script>

$('#myModal').on('show', function() {

// When the modal is shown add Bootstrap's carousel-inner class, move the thumbnails, then invoke the carousel

  $('ul.thumbnails').toggleClass('carousel-inner', true).appendTo($('#myCarousel'));
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});

$('#myModal').on('hide', function() {

// After the modal is dismissed ensure that the active class is removed from all the thumbnails and restore the DOM to the pre-modal state

  $('.thumbnail').each(function() { 
      $(this).toggleClass('active', false).show();
  });    
  $('ul.thumbnails').toggleClass('carousel-inner', false);
  $('ul.thumbnails').appendTo($('section#thumbnails'));
});

$('.thumbnail').click(function() {

// Since the thumbnails already have the data attributes we need to tell the carousel which slide-index to use just toggle the active class

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Bingo! This solution provide by Mike Mayer is exactly what I was looking to achieve, Thanks Mike!!!